# Sequelize - Please install odbc package manually

Tags: node.js, electron, sequelize.js

I've installed sequelize into my electron-vue app.
The installation goes fine, but when I try to start the library I will have a problem with the dialect I want to use, everytime I will get an error message when I use the command `npm run electron:serve`, it will fail to load node odbc and I have it installed as a project dependency. Thi is the code I'm using to load the library

```js
const sequelize = new Sequelize('myDb', 'myuser', 'mypwd', {
    host: '192.168.0.15',
    // one of our supported dialects:
    // 'mysql', 'mariadb', 'postgres', 'mssql', 'sqlite', 'snowflake', 'db2' or 'ibmi'
    dialect: 'ibmi'
});

try {
    sequelize.authenticate()
        .then( () => {
            console.log('Connection ok')
        })
} catch (error) {
    console.log(error)
}
```

The error message is the following `Please install odbc package manually`how I can solve this issue??

Comment: Did you read https://sequelize.org/docs/v7/other-topics/dialect-specific-things/#db2-for-ibm-i ?

Comment: Hi @Anatoly I readed that doc section, but not helped

Comment: Do you have an odbc package installed?  (as mentioned in the error message: "Please install odbc package manually" ), and in the linked page: "The underlying connector library used by Sequelize for Db2 for IBM i is the [odbc](https://www.npmjs.com/package/odbc) npm package."

Comment: @Luuk I have odbc installed as a dependenc, but I don't know why sequelize will not recognize it

Comment: You have to find out (somehow, I do not have an `ibmi`) if the ODBC driver is installed correctly, and can connect to your `myDb`.

Comment: In the windows system the odbc driver is installed, the problem seems to be with the libary that will not recognize the dependency